# How to swap rows in a return set?

Tags: mysql, select

In a table without a sort-order column how do I change the order of the results?

A simple example table is:

```
id | content
1  | Some content here
2  | A page describing something
3  | Row 3 Content
...
7  | Some more content
8  | Row 8 Content
9  | An about-us page
```

Doing a simple select (`SELECT * FROM table`) will return the above in default order.

What I want to do now is change the results so that the row with id 3 is replaced with the row with the id of 8.

So the desired output is:

```
id | content
1  | Some content here
2  | A page describing something
8  | Row 8 Content
...
7  | Some more content
3  | Row 3 Content
9  | An about-us page
```

How do I extend my select query to show my desired output?

Comment: Can you explain how that is sorted?

Comment: Giving an explaination what @dan08 means: the should be a trigger or reason for your order, explain more about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `ORDER BY` using a special `CASE` expression like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY CASE id WHEN 3 THEN 8 WHEN 8 THEN 3 ELSE id END
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no such thing as default order. Without an ORDER BY clause there is no order to the results.

Comment: That's not an answer. This should be a comment.

Comment: dan08 I see your point. Some places though you have to have a minimum amount of reputation to comment. Since my rep is low I don't always remember to check if i can add a comment rather than an answer. Was just trying to add to the thread.